# OAuth Angellist with Firebase

Tags: oauth, firebase

Does Firebase support authentication with oAuth for the provider Angellist?

I tried the following (assuming I have the right access_token):

```
ref.authWithOAuthToken("angellist", access_token, function(error, AuthData) {
          if (error) {
            console.log("Login Failed!", error);
          } else {
            console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", AuthData);
          }
        });
```

but it returned:

```
Error: Invalid authentication provider specified
```

How can this be prevented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Firebase support authentication with oAuth for the provider Angellist?

The list of supported identity providers can be found [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-providers). Angellist is not in there.

Comment: Thank you. Aha I thought that the oAuth function supported all the oAuth providers independently. Nevertheless, I found a work arround with custom tokens.